# Why does increased temperature increase resistance but decreases internal resistance?

Tags: electrical-resistance, electronics

I read that increased temperature increases the resistance because the lattice of metal ions (if we're talking about a wire) vibrates more and so more collisions occur between the electrons and the ions, thus increasing resistance.

However, on reading up about internal resistance, many websites were saying that increased temperature *decreased* the internal resistance. For example: https://www.vedantu.com/question-answer/effect-of-temperature-on-internal-resistance-of-class-11-chemistry-cbse-5fb601994886f710fc005d1f

Why are the relationships between temperature and resistances different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exist both kinds of resistors, so called thermistors it is easiest to read it up in
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistorhttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor
the article you linked is about batteries, so liquid resistors you can not compare with metallic conductors.